# Android studio just through a lot of red lines

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml

I am using android studio and when I opened my project today

[image]

I have no idea what I did. It seemed fine yesterday but I was trying to get google maps to work. I know this is not a lot of info so if there is anything that you think you need to see to try and help me out just let me know.

Comment: Generally issues with R are related to something that went wrong with something inside the `res\` directory. Check to make sure that none of your Layouts xml files have errors. And that none of your Drawables or other resources have issues such as invalid names. Or Perhaps if you changed the package name for your app it might be trying to import from the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try rebuilding the project if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Hm. If you search Stack Overflow for "Android Studio cannot resolve symbol R," you'll find a few other questions about this problem with some more possible solutions. Maybe one of those will do the trick. Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

It happened to me when I shut down my system wrongly. This would work: File menu----invalidate Caches /  Restart... - - - Invalidate and Restart.  When it restart, everything would be alright.

Comment: Only this worked for me. This issue is there in 2.3.2 also. Thanks.

Comment: Same with AS 3.0.0 and kotlin dependencies

Answer (score 2):

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart

It happened to me after upgrading Android Studio to 0.2.6, I used above step to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open "Build Variants"
2. Select another build variant
3. Select correct build variant

Answer (score 0):

`Build`>>`Clean Project`

Solved :) !

Answer (score 0):

if all answers above doesn't solve your problem, just delete the project and import again, it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

you could run

```
 gradle build
```

on the command line ( in your project path ) to see what the root problem is